# Making a big array out of other arrays and IF FALSE making it smaller

Tags: java

I've been working on this program that creates a password, it has 4 char arrays where i have all the characters i can use for the password, and a method that evaluates if the user wants to use them or not, the problem is that it only works when all the arrays are "true"(they are used), because the last array is composed of 73 spaces that are filled with the other arrays.
The problem is that if the user doesnt want to use one of them, when the for loop cycles through the array it will mostly fall on an index number that is empty breaking the code, i cant think of a way of getting over that

```
package javaapplication19;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class JavaApplication19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        char [] leterSmall = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}; 
        char[] leterBig = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','Ñ','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        char[] numbers = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        char [] charsRandom = {'?','¿','.',';','+','-','*','/','|'};
        char [] arrayFinal = new char[73];

        boolean smallOption = false;
        boolean bigOption= false;
        boolean numbersOption= false;
        boolean charactersOption= false;

        System.out.println("Do you want to use small leters?");
        String answer1 = sc.next();
        if( opcionmenu(answer1)==true){
            smallOption = true;
             for(int i=0;i<27;i++){
                arrayFinal[i]=leterSmall[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to use big leters?");
        String answer2 = sc.next();
        if( opcionmenu(answer2)==true){
            bigOption = true;
             for(int i=27;i<54;i++){
                arrayFinal[i]=leterBig[i-27];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Do you  want to use numbers?");
        String answer3 = sc.next();
        if( opcionmenu(answer3)==true){
            numbersOption = true;
             for(int i=54;i<64;i++){
                arrayFinal[i]=numbers[i-54];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to use symbols?");
        String answer4 = sc.next();
        if( opcionmenu(answer4)==true){
            charactersOption = true;
             for(int i=64;i<73;i++){
                arrayFinal[i]=charsRandom[i-64];
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
           int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,73 + 0 );   
           System.out.print(arrayFinal[y]);

        }




    }
       static boolean opcionmenu(String stra){

        if(stra.equals("Yes")) {
             return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
         }
       }              
}
```

Comment: How about tracking the number of array items in a seperate integer and then only adding to that number if an option is true, and then referecing that as your loop integers in the below if statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building `arrayFinal`, keep track of how many values you've added, and only add a value right after a previous value.

Like this, where `len` is the number of characters added to `arrayFinal`:

```
int len = 0;
if (smallOption) {
    for (char c : leterSmall) {
        arrayFinal[len++] = c;
    }
}
if (bigOption) {
    for (char c : leterBig) {
        arrayFinal[len++] = c;
    }
}
if (numbersOption) {
    for (char c : numbers) {
        arrayFinal[len++] = c;
    }
}
if (charactersOption) {
    for (char c : charsRandom) {
        arrayFinal[len++] = c;
    }
}

ThreadLocalRandom rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    System.out.print(arrayFinal[rnd.nextInt(len)]);
}
```

Comment: I didnt understand, i tryed something similar to your code but i got an error msg:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(ThreadLocalRandom.java:378)
 at javaapplication19.JavaApplication19.main(JavaApplication19.java:59)

Comment: @StickyJonson The only way to get that error is if all 4 options are false, i.e. `len` is zero when `nextInt` is called.

Comment: Sorry! I'll try again, the thing is I translated my code, so the keyword was different!! Edit: Now it works, thank you a lot!

Comment: Let me see if i got the thinking behind it right, because im a begginer and i would like to understand this.
So you have an interger that is the amount of characters you've put into the "finalArray" each time the for loop does a "cycle"(i dont know the name of each time it repeats itself) len gets added by 1, but when its false, it just stays the same.
And when you are going to generate a random number for the "finalArray" index the maximun numer is len, so you cant fall into an empty space right?
Sorry im just starting to program

Comment: @StickyJonson Correct. Each *iteration* of the loop adds one more value to the final array. `len` is the number of values in the array, so `nextInt(len)` will always index a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.arraycopy()` method  to . avoid this problem .

such as

```
 int length = 0 ;
if( opcionmenu(answer2)==true){


        System.arraycopy(leterBig ,0 ,arrayFinal,length,leterBig.length);
        length = length + leterBig.length ;


    }
// and so on
for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,length );
            System.out.print(arrayFinal[y]);

        }
```

Comment: Why `- 1`? That would eliminate the last character.